# jQuery Slideshow doesn't work in Chrome

Tags: jquery, nivo-slider

http://bit.ly/OBp1t4

My Nivo slideshow appears to work fine in Safari and Firefox, but doesn't load in Chrome. I'm thinking it has to do with how the jQuery is loading, but I can't pin it down.

Any ideas?

Comment: Please show code relevant to the application. What have you tried to fix this?

Comment: Open up the chrome developer toolbars to see lots of errors.  Most interestingly: 'Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)' on the jquery load.

Comment: It works just fine in my chrome.  Make sure you cleared the cache and restarted.  I notice alot of problems in chrome lately

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are loading http jquery from an HTTPS site.  Use a protocol relative URL, so it does not matter if you are using http or https:

```
//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4/jquery.min.js
```

Comment: This ended up being it, thanks a ton! It was driving me crazy.

Answer (score 0):

There is an error in Chrome console.

```
[blocked] The page at https://www.westwardlook.com/ ran insecure content from http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4/jquery.min.js.
```

This means that jQuery is not loaded and can't be used. That's why Nivo slider does not work. Try to load jQuery (and other scripts) from https instead of http.